# Create short code with some attribute in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-shortcode

I want to create short code from js saved file but i don't know how to send that data from j query on click to Php file.
My js file code is :

```
    jQuery('#create').click(function(){
    var orientation = jQuery('#orientation').val();
    var leftbgcolor = jQuery('.left-bg-color').val();
    var rightbgcolor = jQuery('.right-bg-color').val();
    var fontcolor = jQuery('.font-color').val();
    var titlecolor = jQuery('.title-color').val();
    var image = jQuery('#image').val();
```

I want to send all these data to a php file how would i do that

Answer (score 0):

jQuery part:

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
           orientation: orientation,
           leftbgcolor: leftbgcolor
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType : "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            // callback function

        },
        error: function (error) {
            // error handling
        }
    })
})
```

PHP part

```
 if (isset($_POST['orientation'])){
    $orientation = $_POST['orientation'];
}
```

Change the data, since I used placeholders here and there. Hope this helps you passing on values from jQuery to PHP.

Comment: php does't show that value in my file
any idea how to print that value ?

Comment: Echo $orientation